# Не применяется стиль

Tags: javascript, php, css

Не применяются два стиля для телефона. На ПК все работает. В режиме разработчика показывает, что стили применяются для телефона, а заходя на сайт через телефон эти два стиля не срабатывают.
Задача: Нужно выровнять выбранное значения `option` в `select`.

```
text-align: center; - не работает для телефона
text-align-last: center; - не работает для телефона
```

Код выпадающего списка:

```css
select {
width: 221px;
height: 60px;
padding: 0 5px;
position: relative;
text-align-last: center;
text-align: center;
-ms-text-align-last: center;
-moz-text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-select">
  <select name="razmer" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="37">Выберите размер</option>
    <option class="tovarss" value="1-2 (46-48)" selected="">1-2 (46-48)</option>
    <option class="tovarss" value="2-4 (50-52)">2-4 (50-52)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90378/discussion-on-question-by-lemp---).

Answer (score 0):

Это [баг](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40216) присутствует еще с 2010 года.

Если вы любитель радикальных решений, тогда добавьте немного JS:

```js
function selectChange(el) {
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = el.value
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 221px;
  position: relative;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

span {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 60px;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

select:focus+span {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-select">
  <select name="razmer" onchange="selectChange(this);">
    <option value="37">Выберите размер</option>
    <option class="tovarss" value="1-2 (46-48)" selected="">1-2 (46-48)</option>
    <option class="tovarss" value="2-4 (50-52)">2-4 (50-52)</option>
  </select>
  <span>
      1-2 (46-48)
  </span>
</div>
```